# Query regaring code sequence in pthread example

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

```
int loop = 4;

int a1=0,a2=10;
int b1=100,b2=1000;

int switchs=0;

void* runT1(void* args) {

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<loop; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&locks);
            while(switchs == 1) pthread_cond_wait(&conditions,&locks);
            printf("i=%d a1=%d\n",i,a1++);
            printf("i=%d a2=%d\n",i,a2++);
            switchs = 1;
            pthread_cond_signal(&conditions);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&locks);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* runT2(void* args) {

        int i;
        for(i=0; i<loop; i++) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&locks);
                while(switchs == 0) pthread_cond_wait(&conditions,&locks);
                printf("i=%d b1=%d\n",i,b1++);
                printf("i=%d b2=%d\n",i,b2++);
                switchs = 0;
                pthread_cond_signal(&conditions);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&locks);
        }

        pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void runs(void) {

    pthread_mutex_init(&locks,0);
    pthread_cond_init(&conditions,0);

    pthread_t T1,T2;

    pthread_create(&T1,NULL,runT1,NULL);
    pthread_create(&T2,NULL,runT2,NULL);

    pthread_join(&T1,NULL);
    pthread_join(&T2,NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&locks);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&conditions);
}
```

I am calling `runs()` method from `main()`. It seems it is not giving desired
output printing a1 a2 b1 b2 sequentially 4 times. Please help!!!

Comment: please indent ALL code the required 4 spaces, then repost the code.  Note:: it would also be very helpful if the posted code compiled without any warnings/errors

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What help do you need? Be as specific as possible. Do you need suggestions for how to troubleshoot? What output are you getting? What in the code do you think prevents that output?

Answer (score 2):

With a small handful of fixes needed to make the code compile, it runs fine:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int loop = 4;

int a1=0,a2=10;
int b1=100,b2=1000;

int switchs=0;

pthread_mutex_t locks;
pthread_cond_t conditions;

void* runT1(void* args) {

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<loop; i++) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&locks);
        while(switchs == 1) pthread_cond_wait(&conditions,&locks);
        printf("i=%d a1=%d\n",i,a1++);
        printf("i=%d a2=%d\n",i,a2++);
        switchs = 1;
        pthread_cond_signal(&conditions);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&locks);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* runT2(void* args) {

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<loop; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&locks);
        while(switchs == 0) pthread_cond_wait(&conditions,&locks);
        printf("i=%d b1=%d\n",i,b1++);
        printf("i=%d b2=%d\n",i,b2++);
        switchs = 0;
        pthread_cond_signal(&conditions);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&locks);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void) {

    pthread_mutex_init(&locks,0);
    pthread_cond_init(&conditions,0);

    pthread_t T1,T2;

    pthread_create(&T1,NULL,runT1,NULL);
    pthread_create(&T2,NULL,runT2,NULL);

    void *j;
    pthread_join(T1,&j);
    pthread_join(T2,&j);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&locks);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&conditions);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> i=0 a1=0
>   i=0 a2=10
>   i=0 b1=100
>   i=0 b2=1000
>   i=1 a1=1
>   i=1 a2=11
>   i=1 b1=101
>   i=1 b2=1001
>   i=2 a1=2
>   i=2 a2=12
>   i=2 b1=102
>   i=2 b2=1002
>   i=3 a1=3
>   i=3 a2=13
>   i=3 b1=103
>   i=3 b2=1003

Comment: thanks for fixing the code.  My consideration is the OP requested a fix for executing code, but did not supply executing code.  If the question had been: how do I get this to compile?  I would have willingly did the same as you did.  *I* expect that when the question is about an execution time problem, the posted code compiles/executes.  So I/we can analyse the problem and suggest fixes.  *I* really do not like trying to read the mind of the OP as to what their actual code looks like.